# .show() is not working inside ajaxstart()

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Below is my java script for loading image when ajax is fired.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(function (){
            $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
                $("#ajax_loader").hide();
                //alert("end");
                console.log(new Date().getTime());
            });
            $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
                $("#ajax_loader").show();
                //alert("start");
                console.log(new Date().getTime());
            });
        });
    </script>
```

below is the content I'm hiding/showing.

```
<div id='ajax_loader'
            style="position: fixed; left: 50%; top: 40%; color: red; font-size: 3em; display : none; zIndex : 1;">
            processing.....
        </div>
```

The problem is when any ajax is called the ajaxStart() method is executing but it is not showing the "#ajax_loader" content.

Still the request is taking 2 to 3 secs to respond.

But if we uncomment alert inside ajasStart() method, then it is enabling the "#ajax_loader" content.

Can any please help me on this issue ?

Comment: Is the ajax synchronous? synchronous ajax prevents the callstack from clearing until the ajax is complete, which also prevents the browser from rendering anything, including your loading indicator.

Comment: Yes. it is synchronous.

Comment: put some width;display & border color to check if it showing up or not

Comment: well there's your problem. don't use synchronous ajax. **ever**.

Comment: @KevinB Well that's a good call Kevin. But I have requirement in that way it should be a synchronous. Any help on this ?

Comment: then you can't have a loading indicator. Pick one or the other.

Comment: Yes @KevinB. Once I made it ashnc it is working fine. Thanks for giving me good understanding.

Comment: if you have a "requirement" for it to be synchronous then either a) show the loader via code before calling `$.ajax` or, preferably, b) give the person who gave you the requirement a hard *slap*  (or both)

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to have a loading indicator and synchronous ajax, without executing the ajax in an asynchronous way.

This is because the browser renderer gets put into the callback queue, and the callback queue only gets processed when the callstack is empty. Synchronous ajax prevents the callstack from emptying until the ajax is complete, thus making it impossible to cause anything to render on the page until after it is complete.

One workaround is to wrap the ajax request in a setTimeout, thus allowing the callstack to clear, and the renderer to happen, before the ajax request is sent. However, this will not work with ajaxStart because that doesn't get called until... you guessed it.. the ajax starts. This would likely also break whatever is requiring you to have this as a synchronous request.

The only real solution to this is to not use synchronous ajax and refactor the code that is imposing this crazy requirement on you.

```
async: true
```

Answer (score 0):

This runs just fine just as you wrote it.  Of course, this presumes that the AJAX operation is a valid one.  You might want to open the developer panel in your browser and watch the traffic.

```
    //your part
    jQuery(function() {

        $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
            $("#ajax_loader").hide();
            //alert("end");
            console.log(new Date().getTime());
        });
        $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
            $("#ajax_loader").show();
            //alert("start");
            console.log(new Date().getTime());
        });
    });

    //my part
    jQuery(function() {
        $("#thebutton").click(function() {

            $.ajax({
                crossDomain: true,
                url: "/",
                success: function(e) {
                    var piece = $("<div></div>");
                    piece.html(e);
                    $("#log").append(piece);
                },
                error: function(e) {
                    //alert(e)
                }
            })
        });
    })
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8uhxh9uv/