# How alert is rendered even it is inside synchronous ajax call when the UI is freezed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Below code for global ajax impl.

```
        jQuery(function (){
            $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
                alert("stop");
            });
            $(document).ajaxStart(function() {
                alert("start");
            });
        });
```

I'm doing one **sync ajax call** which takes 5 secs to respond, Since in sync ajax call the whole UI is freeze, but alert is rendered as soon as ajax is called.

In above code, "start" alert comes as soon as ajax called and then after 5 secs "stop" alert rendered.

Please give some understanding.

Comment: I assume you mean that you see the stop alert 5 seconds _after closing_ the start alert?

Comment: which means alert is rendered when sync ajax started. the request takes 5 secs to respond so stop alert comes after 5 secs. I have given this here to make more understanding that alert is rendered when UI is freezed.

Comment: No, the alert is rendered just before the sync ajax is started.  It's only when you close the alert, the code will continue, the request will be made, then stop will show up.

Comment: NO. in the same place instead of alert if you put loaderImg.show()/.hide() will not work. why ?
take a look at this ques http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33131967/show-is-not-working-inside-ajaxstart

Comment: Because that's DOM manipulation, and isn't the same thing as an alert in any shape or form.

Answer (score 0):

Because the start function gets called (by jQuery) before it (jQuery again) triggers the (blocking) XHR request, and the stop function gets called after it.

Comment: This is sync ajax call. the UI changes will not be rendered until sync method finished. take a look at this ques http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33131967/show-is-not-working-inside-ajaxstart

Comment: `alert` is not a UI change - it's a blocking call handled by the browser.  The ajax call won't even start until you close the alert.  Open up your browser developer tools and watch the network traffic.

Comment: @Pavan — That's asking about DOM manipulation. There's no DOM manipulation going on with an alert.

Comment: So the answer is alert is not a DOM manipulation, right ? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Pavan Yes.  Interestingly though, I went to [look at the spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/user-prompts.html#dom-alert) which says "**optionally** pause" - I wonder if there are any implementations that _don't_ pause, can't say I've ever come across one.